# android - How the phone finder service is work?

Tags: android, location

I have a wildfire s device in which the "**phone finder**" service is found. It is used to find the device location when the device is lost. In my device the "phone finder" service has a check box option. Suppose i put this service is ON. How should this work? meaning how/where should i get the device location. because i am not giving any details. please, can anybody help me?

thanks

Comment: i updated the post plz refer that.